# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Random Numbers Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to allow for the button created to randomly generate a value in Tkinter yet i keep getting an error stating

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
global playedNumber

class Paul_Lottery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.winningNumber = randrange(1,10)
        self.userInterface = Tk()
        self.playedNumber = 0


        Label(self.userInterface,text ='Type in your name').pack()
        Entry(self.userInterface,width =100).pack()

        Label(self.userInterface,text= 'Enter a number from 1-10:').pack()
        Entry(self.userInterface,width = 100).pack()
        self.justinNumber = Entry(self.userInterface,width=100)


        self.RandomButton= Button(self.userInterface,text = 'Play',command = self.CheckNumber).pack()
        self.finalresult = StringVar()
        self.finalresultLabel=Label(self.userInterface, textvariable = self.finalresult).pack()
        self.userInterface.mainloop()

    def CheckNumber(self):
            playedNumber = int(self.justinNumber.get())

            if playedNumber==self.winningNumber:
                self.finalresult.set('you are a winner')
            else:
                self.finalresult.set('the winning number is' + str(self.winningNumber) + 'you are not a winner')




def main():
     paul_lottery = Paul_Lottery()

main()
```

I know the string must be converted into a float but confused as to how to do this as i had already set the playedNumber to 0 as an integer.

Comment: It doesn't matter what a variable references currently if you subsequently reassign it to something else. It looks like `playedNumber = int(self.justinNumber.get())` is causing the problem. What does `self.justinNumber.get()` return?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert a string to an integer, but the string may contain something that is not convertible to an int. You should handle this by catching the ValueError exception. For example

```
try:
   playedNumber = int(self.justinNumber.get())
except ValueError as e:
   # Do something reasonable when this error occurs such as
   # 1. Logging an error to help you debug
   # 2. Resetting the widget to a valid state
   # 3. Give the user some feedback (such as a warning message)
   print('Failed to convert to int {}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty string (i.e. `''`) to your `int()` method, which is what your error is telling you. It looks to me like you are either pressing your `RandomButton` without anything entered in the `justinNumber` field (thus an empty string), or your `CheckNumber()` method is getting triggered automatically somehow before you are able to enter a guess in your `justinNumber` field. I think that's where your error is coming from. Note that your `CheckNumber()` method is still looking in this field for a guess, not checking a random number.

To have the button randomly generate a number, how about you just create a new method, call it `random_guess()` defined like this:

```
def random_guess(self):
    guess = np.random.randint(1, 10)
    if guess == self.winningNumber:
        self.finalresult.set('you are a winner')
    else:
        self.finalresult.set('the winning number is' + str(self.winningNumber) + 'you are not a winner')
```

Then tie that to your random button with:

```
self.RandomButton = Button(self.userInterface, text='Play',
                           command=self.random_geuss).pack()
```

And if you want to get fancy, I encourage you to find a way to minimize repeated code before `random_guess()` and your `CheckNumber()` on your own!

Comment: I'm getting an error where it's stating that 'self is not defined'.

Comment: Add the function definition in my answer inside of your class definition, not outside of it.

Comment: NameError: name 'playedNumber' is not defined, and i've placed  inside my class definition i believe. I tried creating a separate function where playednumber was equal to guess.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had a typo. That test should have been `guess == ...` instead. I corrected it in my answer if you want to see if that works. Upvote/accept please if it helped!